# Iterating Over Terraform Locals Results In No Change to Infrastructure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is what my locals looks like:

```
  locals {
    preprocessed = {
      "first" = {
        tags = {
          name = "test"
          env  = "dev"
        }
        users = [
          "Admin",
          "DataEng"
        ]
        group_parameters = [
          {
            name         = "rds.logical_replication"
            value        = "1"
            apply_method = "pending-reboot"
          }
        ]
      }
    
    processed = {
          for instance, settings in local.preprocessed : instance => {
            tags = settings.tags
            user_roles = [
              for role in settings.admin_user_roles : 
                "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/${role}"
              ]
            group_parameters = settings.group_parameters
         }
       }
   }
```

The result that I expect from this I verified looks good using terraform console, it looks like this:

```
processed = {
    "first" = {
      "group_parameters" = [
        {
          "apply_method" = "pending-reboot"
          "name"         = "rds.logical_replication"
          "value"        = "1"
        }
      ]
      "tags" = {
        "env"                            = "dev"
        "name"                           = "test"
      }
      "user_roles" = [
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/Admin",
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/DataEng"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now the processed local is used to loop over this resource:

```
module "kms_key" {
  for_each = local.processed

  source                     = "git@github.com:xyz/kms.git?ref=v1.0"
  external_access_principals = each.value["user_roles"]
  key_alias                  = each.key
  key_description            = "key to encrypt ${each.key} instance"
  tags                       = each.key.tags
}
```

This however evaluates to `No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.` When using local.processed.

The strange thing is if I were to replace the local.processed with another local var that contains the copy-pasted output I got from terraform console [ i.e. the already processed result ] it results in TF trying to create one resource [ i.e. has one member in the local param over which it is looping]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is going on. Was there anything related to that module before this change or not?

Comment: No, it was not related to the module. In summary I had an incorrect object definition in my variable declaration [ by incorrect i mean no def, thought object({}) could accept any value in it ]. I have posted a more detailed answer. Not defining the object correctly would result in the loop being null and no error being thrown, thanks for taking a look though ! @MarkoE

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the type definition for the variable processed. I had initially declared it like so:

```
variable "processed" {
  type = object({})
  description = "object with each element representing one instance"
  default     = null
}
```

and my understanding was that the object can then take anything. But, what was really needed there was this:

```
variable "processed" {
  type = map(object({
    tags                          = map(string)
    user_roles                    = list(string)
    group_parameters = list(map(string))
  }))
  description = "object with each element representing one instance"
  default     = null
}
```

frustrating that this failed silently and the plan showed that my TF is inline with the infrastructure.